# Understanding the use of the keyword every

Tags: gnuplot

My question regards the keyword `every` that is used to sample an input data file (i.e., `.csv`, `.dat` etc.). I am reading the documentation of the keyword that says the following:

```
     plot 'file' every {<point_incr>}
                         {:{<block_incr>}
                           {:{<start_point>}
                             {:{<start_block>}
                               {:{<end_point>}
                                 {:<end_block>}}}}}
```

The thing is I cannot completely comprehend how to adapt this to a data set. For instance, if I have some dummy data that I wish to use to create a bar chart for example and the data are the following

```
# first bars group
#x axis   #y axis
0          2
0.2        3                  
0.4        4                  
0.6        5                 
0.8        6                 
                             
#second bars group           
1          1 
1.2        2
1.4        3
1.6        4
1.8        5

#etc.
3     10
3.2   20
3.4   30
3.6   40
3.8   50 

4     20
4.2   30
4.4   40
4.6   50
4.8   60
```

And lets say that I want to create four bar clusters from the data. One for every block. How can I use the syntax of the keyword? Could someone give me some examples to better understand the use of it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, the `every` keyword allows you to cherry-pick a subset of single-newline-separated *points* and double-newline-separated *blocks* from your datafile. Your example datafile shows 20 points divided into 4 blocks.

So to plot the first block (indexed 0 in gnuplot), you only need to specify the end block, and use the default values for the other `every` parameters. Try:

```
plot 'data.txt' every :::::0 with boxes
```

It seems your goal is to plot each block with separate styling. Here's how you could do that with a few extra styling commands. (Note my use of gnuplot's shorthand for some keywords.)

```
set key left top
set boxwidth 0.2
p 'data.txt' ev :::0::0 w boxes t 'first',\
  'data.txt' ev :::1::1 w boxes t 'second',\
  'data.txt' ev :::2::2 w boxes t 'third',\
  'data.txt' ev :::3::3 w boxes t 'fourth'
```

[image: example histogram]

Answer (score 1):

From `help every`:

> The data points to be plotted are selected according to a loop from
> <start_point> to <end_point> with increment <point_incr> and the
> blocks according to a loop from <start_block> to <end_block> with
> increment <block_incr>.

This should be pretty clear, however, you have to know if blocks are separated by two (or more) empty lines, you have to address them differently. Check `help index`. To my opinion the documentation is a bit confusing about datablock, (sub-)block, dataset, etc...

Check the following example. I assume this is not your final graph, but still needs some tuning. Depending on your detailed requirements you also might want to check `help histograms`.

For example `every :::i::i` will plot all datapoints in in block `i`, i.e. from block `i` to block `i`.

**Code:**

```
### plotting using "every"
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# first bars group
#x axis   #y axis
0          2
0.2        3
0.4        4
0.6        5
0.8        6
            
#second bars group
1          1 
1.2        2
1.4        3
1.6        4
1.8        5

#etc.
3     10
3.2   20
3.4   30
3.6   40
3.8   50 

4     20
4.2   30
4.4   40
4.6   50
4.8   60 
EOD

set key top left
set boxwidth 0.2
set key out noautotitles
set style fill solid 0.3
set yrange [:70]

plot for [i=0:3] $Data u 1:2 every :::i::i w boxes
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]